# How split column of list-values into multiple columns?

Tags: r, list, split, dplyr

I have the following situation, the column `power_dbm0` has values as list. All elements are list of length 11.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   real_pat power_dbm0
   <chr>    <list>    
 1 am       <dbl [11]>
 2 fax      <dbl [11]>
 3 fp       <dbl [11]>
 4 fpw      <dbl [11]>
```

I'd like to know how could split theses values as each order is a new column. Preferably, i'd like a dplyr-like solution. I have tried some solutions with `unnest` or `separate` function from `tidyr`, but it didn't success.

Thanks in advance,

Follow the data:

```
structure(list(real_pat = c("am", "fax", "fp", "fpw"), power_dbm0 = list(
    structure(c(0.0142857142857143, 0.0742857142857143, 0.111428571428571, 
    0.138571428571429, 0.208571428571429, 0.278571428571429, 
    0.368571428571429, 0.508571428571429, 0.648571428571429, 
    0.771428571428571, 0.871428571428571), .Names = c("0%", "10%", 
    "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"
    )), structure(c(0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143, 
    0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143, 
    0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143, 
    0.342857142857143, 0.342857142857143), .Names = c("0%", "10%", 
    "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"
    )), structure(c(0.0142857142857143, 0.622857142857143, 0.808571428571429, 
    0.851428571428571, 0.857142857142857, 0.871428571428571, 
    0.874285714285714, 0.885714285714286, 0.894285714285714, 
    0.911428571428571, 0.914285714285714), .Names = c("0%", "10%", 
    "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"
    )), structure(c(0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714, 
    0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714, 
    0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714, 
    0.514285714285714, 0.514285714285714), .Names = c("0%", "10%", 
    "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"
    )))), .Names = c("real_pat", "power_dbm0"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example and also your expected output.  It is not clear what is in each list element

Comment: thanks for the hint, i've added.

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% mutate(power_dbm0 = map(power_dbm0, as_tibble)) %>% unnest`

Comment: No, i'd like to put each order as a column, not melt all values in the same column.

Comment: Please check the solution I posted.

Answer (score 8):

**1)** This is a one-line base solution:

```
with(dd, do.call("rbind", setNames(power_dbm0, real_pat)))
```

giving:

```
            0%        10%       20%       30%       40%       50%       60%
am  0.01428571 0.07428571 0.1114286 0.1385714 0.2085714 0.2785714 0.3685714
fax 0.34285714 0.34285714 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571
fp  0.01428571 0.62285714 0.8085714 0.8514286 0.8571429 0.8714286 0.8742857
fpw 0.51428571 0.51428571 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857
          70%       80%       90%      100%
am  0.5085714 0.6485714 0.7714286 0.8714286
fax 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571
fp  0.8857143 0.8942857 0.9114286 0.9142857
fpw 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857
```

**2)** or to get the `real_pat` as a column rather than names:

```
with(dd, data.frame(real_pat, do.call("rbind", power_dbm0), check.names = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
  real_pat         0%        10%       20%       30%       40%       50%
1       am 0.01428571 0.07428571 0.1114286 0.1385714 0.2085714 0.2785714
2      fax 0.34285714 0.34285714 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571
3       fp 0.01428571 0.62285714 0.8085714 0.8514286 0.8571429 0.8714286
4      fpw 0.51428571 0.51428571 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857
        60%       70%       80%       90%      100%
1 0.3685714 0.5085714 0.6485714 0.7714286 0.8714286
2 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571
3 0.8742857 0.8857143 0.8942857 0.9114286 0.9142857
4 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857
```

**3)** Using dplyr we could write this:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% { bind_cols(select(., real_pat), bind_rows(!!!.$power_dbm0)) }
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  real_pat   `0%`  `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 am       0.0143 0.0743 0.111 0.139 0.209 0.279 0.369 0.509 0.649 0.771  0.871
2 fax      0.343  0.343  0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343  0.343
3 fp       0.0143 0.623  0.809 0.851 0.857 0.871 0.874 0.886 0.894 0.911  0.914
4 fpw      0.514  0.514  0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514  0.514
```

**3a)** or using the `.id=` argument of `bind_rows` and the magrittr `%$%` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

dd %$%
   setNames(power_dbm0, real_pat) %$%
   bind_rows(!!!., .id = "real_pat")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  real_pat   `0%`  `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 am       0.0143 0.0743 0.111 0.139 0.209 0.279 0.369 0.509 0.649 0.771  0.871
2 fax      0.343  0.343  0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343  0.343
3 fp       0.0143 0.623  0.809 0.851 0.857 0.871 0.874 0.886 0.894 0.911  0.914
4 fpw      0.514  0.514  0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514  0.514
```

**3b)** or without `%$%` :

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>%
   { setNames(.$power_dbm0, .$real_pat) } %>%
   { bind_rows(!!!., .id = "real_pat") }
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  real_pat   `0%`  `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 am       0.0143 0.0743 0.111 0.139 0.209 0.279 0.369 0.509 0.649 0.771  0.871
2 fax      0.343  0.343  0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343  0.343
3 fp       0.0143 0.623  0.809 0.851 0.857 0.871 0.874 0.886 0.894 0.911  0.914
4 fpw      0.514  0.514  0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514  0.514
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** We could `transpose` the 'power_dbm0' column, `unlist` the `nested` list and then bind with the first column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   pull(power_dbm0) %>%
   transpose %>%
   map_df(unlist) %>% 
   bind_cols(df1[1], .)
# A tibble: 4 x 12
#   real_pat   `0%`  `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
#  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 am       0.0143 0.0743 0.111 0.139 0.209 0.279 0.369 0.509 0.649 0.771  0.871
#2 fax      0.343  0.343  0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343  0.343
#3 fp       0.0143 0.623  0.809 0.851 0.857 0.871 0.874 0.886 0.894 0.911  0.914
#4 fpw      0.514  0.514  0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514  0.514
```

---

**2)**  Or another option would be to `melt` and then do a `spread`.  Here, we also include `unnest` as the OP mentioned in the post

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(power_dbm0 = map(power_dbm0, ~melt(.x) %>% 
                          rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
                          mutate(rn = factor(rn, levels = rn)))) %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    spread(rn, value)
# A tibble: 4 x 12
#  real_pat   `0%`  `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
#  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 am       0.0143 0.0743 0.111 0.139 0.209 0.279 0.369 0.509 0.649 0.771  0.871
#2 fax      0.343  0.343  0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343 0.343  0.343
#3 fp       0.0143 0.623  0.809 0.851 0.857 0.871 0.874 0.886 0.894 0.911  0.914
#4 fpw      0.514  0.514  0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514 0.514  0.514
```

---

**3)** Or with `pmap` and `spread`

```
df1 %>%
     pmap_df(~ tibble(real_pat = ..1, nm = names(..2), val = ..2))  %>%
     spread(nm, val)
```

NOTE: All the solutions used `dplyr` and related packages in the `tidyverse`

---

**4)** Or we could `unlist` the 'power_dbm0', create a `matrix` as they are all equal length and then bind with the first column (`base R`) - The column names can be changed if needed

```
data.frame(df1[1], matrix(unlist(df1$power_dbm0), ncol = 11, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: nice solution, but i was wondering if exists a direct function or a more straight-forward procedure to reach this transformation.

Answer (score 2):

An option can be as:

```
cbind(df[1],t(sapply(df$power_dbm0,function(x)x)))

# real_pat         0%        10%       20%       30%       40%       50%       60%       70%       80%       90%      100%
# 1       am 0.01428571 0.07428571 0.1114286 0.1385714 0.2085714 0.2785714 0.3685714 0.5085714 0.6485714 0.7714286 0.8714286
# 2      fax 0.34285714 0.34285714 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571 0.3428571
# 3       fp 0.01428571 0.62285714 0.8085714 0.8514286 0.8571429 0.8714286 0.8742857 0.8857143 0.8942857 0.9114286 0.9142857
# 4      fpw 0.51428571 0.51428571 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857 0.5142857
```

Additional option using `simplify2array` (based on feedback from @@G.Grothendieck):

```
cbind(df[1],t(simplify2array(df$power_dbm0)))
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Agreed. That would be even simpler option. I'll update my answer.